# Google apps script to delete rows triggered by manual cell edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help writing a google apps script to delete rows on Google Sheets. Here are the exact requirements of the script: The script should delete all the rows on my sheet called "Proposal-Email" for which the 3rd column (column C) has a value of "x". This script should be triggered when the user manually changes the value of cell A2 (on the same sheet) to "x". Any help with this is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

- You could use [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers)() to trigger when the cell is edited
- In the function, check for the cell value using `IF` and delete the row.